# Change the executable name in Eclipse for C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, build, executable, filenames

I've created a C++ project in Eclipse and currently it builds an executable called file.exe but I want to change this to "file".

How do I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean, you want to remove the file extension?

Comment: yes so when build the file on a Linux machine I can run it with ./file instead of ./file.exe

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot remove the .exe from the filename, because windows uses this to determine the file type, and be removing the .exe, then it will not know that the file is an executable.

Comment: I seldom use Windows from command line, one of the times I do that is when I need to run "ipconfig". I found that I could run `ipconfig` as well as `ipconfig.exe`.

Comment: Downvote: This explanation might be helpful, BUT ... it does not answer the question. Please post this kind of answer as a comment next time, not as an answer. I had the same question and searched for it and then was pointed to this page. For the real answer, see my post below.

Answer (score 14):

To change the name of the executable and it's extension go to:

**Project Settings > C/C++ Build > Settings > Build Artifact**

Comment: Works in Linux too -- good solution for making the executable name different from the project name.

Comment: This helped me solve a problem where the linker could not write the executable because it was interpreted as a directory name (errno = 21). Thanks!